# BigQuery - count the count of a column

Tags: google-bigquery

Newbie on SQL and BigQuery in general.  How to count the count of a column in BigQuery? As you can see from the code sample, the query returns the count of appName as WhitelistNames, but I would like to get a count of WhitelistNames.

```
SELECT
COUNT(appName) AS WhitelistNames,
  bridgeToken
FROM (
  SELECT
    bridgeToken,
    appName
  FROM
    [DB]
  GROUP BY
    bridgeToken,
    appName )
GROUP BY
  bridgeToken
ORDER BY
  WhitelistNames DESC
```

Current query return is:

```
Row UniquebridgeToken   WhitelistEntries    
1   11111               5         
2   22222               13    
3   33333               3     
4   44444               3
5   55555               3
```

But I would like to count the occurrence of UniquebridgeToken like below.  Thanks in advance.:

```
Row WhitelistEntries    BridgeCount
1   13                  1
2   5                   1
3   3                   3
```

Comment: At present in your query WhitelistNames represents an alias of the count of appname, what else do you want to count?

Comment: I wrote more details in the description to explain the desired results better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and based on how I interpreted your question  - which is:
for each `bridgeToken` how many unique `appName`'s and how many total entries (rows) for that bridge

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT appName) AS WhitelistNames, 
  COUNT(bridgeToken) AS BridgeCount
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
GROUP BY bridgeToken
```

Comment: Excuse me for the delayed response. I've edited my question to make it more clear.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want is to count how many UniquebridgeToken have the same number of WhitelistEntries. I think what you are looking for is that:

```
WITH nestedQuery AS (SELECT
    appName,
    COUNT(appName) as WhitelistEntries
FROM `project_name.dataset_name.table_name`
GROUP BY 
     price)

SELECT n.WhitelistEntries, COUNT(n.WhitelistEntries) as BridgeCount
FROM nestedQuery as n
GROUP BY n.WhitelistEntries
```

You can read about WITH clause here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause